# C# and MySql Is the connection to MySql secure?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I am creating an application for windows desktop, with which I connect to a MySql database that I have created in a hosting (I have referenced MySql.Data, installing the MySql connector before). The problem is that I have read that this method is very very insecure. I don't know if I would have to put the connection data in the exe.config, encrypt it in some way, and the sentences the same, since they say that they can decompile the program and see the data, or do some injection, or with some listener program in linux type Kali wireshark the data could be captured. I would need advice please. To give you an idea of how I make the connection and how I delete or insert data:
Connection (it is in a class):

```
        public static MySqlConnection conexionBD;
        public static void Iniciar_Conexion_BBDD(String servidor, String puerto, String usuario, String password, String bd)
        {
            servidor = "servidor";
            puerto = "3306";
            usuario = "usuario";
            password = "pass";
            bd = "basedatos";

            String cadenaConexion = $"Database={bd}; Data Source={servidor}; Port={puerto}; User Id={usuario}; Password={password}";

            conexionBD = new MySqlConnection(cadenaConexion);
            try
            {
                conexionBD.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Insert data to the DB, then I update the DGV:

```
        private void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            String tabla = txtTabla.Text;

            try
            {
                String agregar = $"INSERT INTO {tabla} VALUES ('{txtId.Text}','{txtNombre.Text}','{txtApellidos.Text}','{txtEdad.Text}','{txtCodigo.Text}');";

                MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(agregar);
                comando.Connection = Conexion.conexionBD;
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                CargaDatosDGV_Click_1(null, null); // Actualizo datos del DGV
                MessageBox.Show("Datos agregados correctamente.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
            }
        }
```

Delete data from the DB and then refresh DGV

```
        private void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            String tabla = txtTabla.Text;

            try
            {
                String agregar = $"DELETE FROM {tabla} WHERE Id = '{dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Id"].Value.ToString()}'"; // El registro seleccionado

                MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(agregar);
                comando.Connection = Conexion.conexionBD;
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                CargaDatosDGV_Click_1(null, null);
                MessageBox.Show("Datos borrados correctamente.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
            }

        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: This may help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/protecting-connection-information

Comment: I think the main point, you're using string concatenations to build your sql commands.  You should always use parameters.  Not only for the security aspect, but also makes your code much less error prone and maintainable